# Android - displaying alert dialog during doinbackground while catching exception

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask, try-catch, android-alertdialog

I have this code and it goes to catch as soon as it hits `Source.httpConn` and it sends the exception down below to catch.

```
         try
            {
            JSONTokener sbTokener = new JSONTokener(Source.httpConn(infoUrlStr, Main.this).toString());
            //array için hazırlandı

            JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(sbTokener);
            //arraye eklendi
            for(int i=0; i<(jArray.length()); i++)
    .
    .
    .
     }
```

Down in the catch part there is my alert dialog method. It normally works pretty well but I suspect that I have the problem because of the `doInBackground`. The application crashes before displaying the below alert dialog. All the try-catch is in my `doInBackground` method in `ASyncTask`.

```
                 catch (Exception e) {
                        AlertDialogDisp(Main.this, noServ, noServLog);
                    }
```

How can I make my application NOT crash and just display this alert dialog and then return to my Main activity as it was. Here is my alert dialog method:

```
      protected void AlertDialogDisp(Context dialogContext, String head, String log) {


    new AlertDialog.Builder(dialogContext)
    .setTitle(head)
    .setMessage(log)
    .setPositiveButton("okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // On Alert Dialog Button
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })

    .show();
}
```

Comment: is your aynsctask an inner class of activity class?

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update ui from `doInbackground`. `doInbackground` is invoked on a backgroudn thread. Ui should be updated on the ui thread. Return result in `doInbackground` and update ui in `onPostExecute`

For more info check the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can also use `runOnUithread` which is a method of activity class

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
           // dispaly dialog here
           // no network related operation here
        }
     });
```

Comment: that's the problem, how will I do that? I can return the result but I need to display that alertdialog if doinbackground fails

Comment: @SuhrahjRothgar return a result a status like 0 0r 1 or boolean and display a dialog in `onPostExecute`. i don't see a problem with that

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm a bit sleepy :D I get it, thanks a lot, this is pretty good!

Answer (score 1):

Show your dialog in `runOnUiThead` which is a method of activity class.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {

                  //write your alert dialog code here

        }
     });
```

Comment: if you run n/w related operation on the ui thread you get a exception. i don't think you require try catch here. only in catch op is displaying dialog so dialog code should be in the run method

Comment: but why do you require try catch to display alert dialog?

Comment: you can remove it. this is not a issue